# How use bootstrap-sass efficiently?

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm, sass

I'm currently discovering modules with npm, and I went to use [bootstrap-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-sass). Now that the modules were downloaded, I was looking for a solution to compile scss into the static folder of the application, and also the js bootstrap files.

But according to npmjs documentation of the modules, I can't found a simple solution which is not to move the js files myself and compile the scss bootstrap files from node_modules with something like node-sass.

What is the simplest way to use this module correctly and with the possibility to custom ?

**Edit :**

For now, I am using the following scripts/files :

```
"compile-js": "browserify assets/static/js/main.js | uglifyjs > assets/static/js/bundle.js",
"compile-sass": "node-sass assets/scss/app.scss assets/static/css/app.css --output-style compressed"
```

***app.scss***

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap-sprockets.scss";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";
```

***main.js***

```
global.jQuery = require("jquery")
const bootstrap = require('bootstrap-sass');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `bootstrap-sass` before, but the documentation implies that a build tool to preprocess the SCSS is a prerequisite for using this module. While it's no longer the shiniest tool in the shed, [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com) is very capable of handling this task as well as moving the files from `node_modules` to your project root directory for you.

Here's a breakdown of one approach to implement this:

1. Create three subfolders in your project root directory and call them `sass`, `css` and `javascript`.
2. Create a file in the `sass` folder and call it `app.scss`. Open it and paste this: `@import './node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss';`. When the file is converted into CSS, all of the Bootstrap modules will be there. Beneath the `@import` statement on line 1, feel free to write whatever style rules you want.
3. Assuming you have already run `npm init` and have a `package.json` file in your project directory, run `npm install gulp -D` in your terminal. This installs gulp (my task runner of choice!).
4. Run `npm install gulp-sass --save-dev`. This installs the gulp plugin that will preprocess the Bootstrap SASS into CSS.
5. Create a file in your root directory (not in any of the subfolders) called `gulpfile.js`
6. Copy and paste this text into `gulpfile.js`:

(note: for this to work, your SASS and CSS folders must be called `sass` and `css`, respectively, unless you change their names in the following code.)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass-to-css', function () {
    return gulp.src('./sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('javascript', function () {
    return gulp.src('./node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./javascript'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass-to-css', 'javascript']);
```

Lastly, run the command `gulp` in your terminal to execute the gulpfile, which will do two things:

1. Preprocess and move all of the SASS into your `css` folder.
2. Copy `bootstrap.min.js` from `node_modules` into your project's `javascript` folder.

Of course, don't forget to link to these assets in your HTML.

I whipped up this gulpfile on the fly and it works on my machine, but if you decide to try this approach then feel free to ask if something throws an error. Best of luck on your project.